# Get data from multiple inputs with the same name

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a large form and I have passing this data to php via ajax. I am saving this data in a string with jQuery `serialize` function.
Here is my code

```
var form_data = jQuery(this).serializeArray();
form_data = JSON.stringify(form_data);
```

In php I have converted this in array via `json_decode` function.

Here is an example for this array

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
    [name] => fname
    [value] => MyFirstName
)

[1] => Array
(
    [name] => lname
    [value] => MyLastName
)
 [2] => Array
(
    [name] => institution_name[]
    [value] => institution1
)

[3] => Array
(
    [name] => degree_name[]
    [value] => Graduated
)
[4] => Array
(
    [name] => institution_name[]
    [value] => institution2
)
[5] => Array
(
    [name] => degree_name[]
    [value] => Graduating
)
)
```

I am able to get other input fields in a loop but struggling to get values from input fields with the same name. For example in above example we have degree_name and institution_name multiple time. 
I will appreciate your suggestion as I am new with php.

Answer (score 1):

I used to use foreach

```
   $new = array();
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $new[$key] => $value;
    }

    var_dump($new);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP's way of handling multiple form inputs with the same name is to turn them into arrays.

That's what the `[]` suffix in their names denotes.

So to access their various values (i.e. for each field of that name), look inside the array.

```
$_POST['degree_name'][0]; //the value of the first field with [name=degree_name]
$_POST['degree_name'][1]; //the value of the 2nd field with [name=degree_name]
//...etc
```

Comment: I have tried this already but it is not returning correct value. For example in first degree[] field value is Graduation then for [0] it is returning 'G' for [1] it is returning 'r' etc..